# Add a general style inside a react component

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

How can I add general styles to my page inside of one of my components. For example, I when my components loads, I want to add a style like this to whole page:

```
*{
 direction:rtl;
}
```

and when the component unmounts, I want the style to be removed. I am using css modules for styling.

Comment: Have you tried Higher Order Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it using jsx style:

```
<style jsx="true">
              {`
                * {
                   direction:rtl;
                  }
             `}
</style>
```